# if condition in urls.py - django

Tags: python, html, django, session, django-templates

I want to check **if user not loged**(don't have a session) he **go to login.html** file and **if he loged**(have a session) he go to **profile.html** , but i want to check it at urls.py

My projects Tree :

```
manage.py
url
----setting.py
mr_url
-----templates
---------url
------------profile.html
------------login
-----------------logon.html
-----views.py
-----models.py
-----urls.py
```

My `urls.py` :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

**How i can check set session for user or not in *urls.py***  ????

**Note** : i can do it in `views.py` but i don't want!

Comment: You can manage it from views.py easily. Why you want to tackle this from urls.py ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `login_required` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.profile), name='profile'),
]
```

If the user is not logged in, he will be redirected to the login page whose default is `accounts/login`. You can customize it by setting `LOGIN_URL` in your settings.

Hope it helps!